# How to lower input resistance of buffer (unity-gain) op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, input-impedance, single-supply-op-amp

[image: Unity Gain Buffer]

A practical op-amp connected in a unity gain configuration will have a very high input resistance (mega-ohms or higher). How can I add an external resistor to modify the input resistance to the kilo-ohm range (while keeping the output resistance low)? Can I connect a resistor between the inverting and non-inverting terminal?

Comment: Would adding a resistor from Vin to ground be okay? Anything you put there will provide an input resistance.

Comment: @jonk, would a resistor from Vin to ground appear in parallel with the op-amp's high input resistance? If that is the case, then the resistor will approximately set the input resistance.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? After 13 years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A resistor from In+ to In- is not ideal to lower input impedance. [It increases noise](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/608127/237061) and has a capacitor-like impedance due to the feedback that constantly eliminates the voltage across this resistor. Its DC impedance will be very high.

To get what you want, add a resistor from In+ to a fixed voltage node, instead. E.g. to Gnd or to one of the opamp supplies.

Answer (score 9):

Here you go:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1JXK2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input resistance is now 10kΩ, and the output resistance isn't affected at all!